# Error Command "encore" not found. (separate backend webpack)

Tags: symfony, yarnpkg, webpack-encore

directory structure

```
admin/ -> backend webpack
  js/
  .yarnrc
  webpack.config.js
  package.json
assets/ -> frond webpack
```

admin/ files content :

.yarnrc

```
--modules-folder node_modules_admin
```

This correctly create admin/node_modules_admin 
Admin use boostrap 3, Front use boostrap 4 so need separate folders.

webpack.config.js

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // the project directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('./../public/admin/')
    // the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
    .setPublicPath('/admin')
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .createSharedEntry('vendor', [
        'jquery',
        'bootstrap',
        // 'fullcalendar',
        './js/vendor.js',
        // you can also extract CSS - this will create a 'vendor.css' file
        // this CSS will *not* be included in page1.css or page2.css anymore
        // 'bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss'
    ])

    .addEntry('js/admin', './js/admin.js')
    .addEntry('js/datatables', './js/datatables.js')
    .addStyleEntry('css/appLess', './css/app.less')
    .addStyleEntry('css/admin', './css/admin.scss')

    // uncomment to define the assets of the project
    // .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
    // .addStyleEntry('css/app', './assets/css/app.scss')

    // uncomment if you use Sass/SCSS files
    .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment for legacy applications that require $/jQuery as a global variable
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .autoProvideVariables({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
    })
    // .enableVersioning()
    .enableLessLoader()
    // .addLoader(
    //     {test: require.resolve('signature_pad'), loader: 'expose?SignaturePad'},
    // )
    .enableBuildNotifications()

    // .addLoader(
    //     {
    //         test: require.resolve('wow.js/dist/wow.js'),
    //         loader: 'exports?this.WOW'
    //     })
    .addLoader(
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
            loader:"file-loader",
            query:{
                name:'[name].[ext]',
                outputPath:'images/'
                //the images will be emmited to public/assets/images/ folder
                //the images will be put in the DOM <style> tag as eg. background: url(assets/images/image.png);
            }
        })

;

let config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();

config.resolve.alias = {
    'handlebars': 'handlebars/dist/handlebars.min.js'
};

// module.exports = {
//     entry: [
//         'fullcalendar',
//         ...
//     ]
// }

module.exports = config;
```

package.json

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.21.0",
        "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
        "less": "^3.0.4",
        "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "admin-lte": "^2.4.8",
        "bootstrap-editable": "^1.0.1",
        "datatables-all": "^1.10.13",
        "datatables-buttons": "^1.0.3",
        "datatables-fixedheader": "^3.1.0",
        "datatables.net": "^1.10.19",
        "datatables.net-bs": "^1.10.19",
        "datatables.net-buttons-bs": "^1.5.1",
        "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.19",
        "datatables.net-fixedheader-bs": "^3.1.3",
        "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^3.1.3",
        "fullcalendar": "^2.9.1",
        "handlebars": "^4.0.12",
        "jquery": "^2.2.4",
        "jquery-form": "^4.2.2",
        "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
        "jquery-ui-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
        "jquery-validation": "^1.18.0",
        "jquery.fancytree": "^2.30.0",
        "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
        "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
        "popover": "^2.4.1",
        "readmore-js": "^2.2.1",
        "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
        "select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1",
        "timeago": "^1.6.3",
        "timeago.js": "^4.0.0-beta.1",
        "webpack-icons-installer": "^2.0.0",
        "webpack-jquery-ui": "^2.0.1",
        "x-editable": "^1.5.1"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production"
    }
}
```

config/framework.yaml

```
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #default_locale: en
    #csrf_protection: true
    #http_method_override: true

    # Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY be started if you read or write from it.
    # Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
    session:
        handler_id: ~

    assets:
        packages:
            backend:
                json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/admin/manifest.json'
            frontend:
                json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'
```

I go to admin directory

```
~/PhpstormProjects/vista_bralion_docker/admin$ yarn install
yarn install v1.12.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.94s.
```

try generate files

```
~/PhpstormProjects/vista_bralion_docker/admin$ yarn run encore dev --watch 
yarn run v1.12.1
error Command "encore" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I try direct run encore

```
:~/PhpstormProjects/vista_bralion_docker/admin$ node_modules_admin/@symfony/webpack-encore/bin/encore.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/grek/PhpstormProjects/vista_bralion_docker/admin/node_modules_admin/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/config/parse-runtime.js:15:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
```

here is admin/yarn.lock

https://pastebin.com/cpYSxbRz

Comment: What's in yarn.lock ?

Comment: i upload admin/yarn.lock to paste bin - cannot paste here body size limit https://pastebin.com/cpYSxbRz

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to execute this command:

```
$ yarn add --dev vue vue-loader@15.x vue-template-compiler
```

This is the result:

[image]

then everything works fine

[image]

Other solution possible is this:

- Remove the node_modules directory and the yarn.lock file if you have one
- After: 
  `yarn run --ignore-engines`

I use this on cloudways with digital ocean

[Referencia](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/251#issuecomment-360779407)